# Is my solution of $\frac{d }{dx}\int_0^{\cos x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt$ correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$\frac{d }{dx}\int_0^{\cos x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{1+\cos^4x}-1)dx}{dx}$$
$$\sqrt{1+\cos^4x}-1$$
The answer seems weird to me, but I see no other way to do this. Was this correct? If not, how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus? Suppose $F$ is the antiderivative So we have $(F(\cos x) - F(0))' = F'(\cos x)\cdot\sin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the answers are correct, but do not really explain why.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t)dt\right)$$

Let $H(t)$ be any antiderivative of $h(t)$. In other words, $\dfrac{d}{dt}H(t) = h(t)$.

Now, we can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to the integral:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t)dt\right) = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(H(g(x))-H(f(x)) \right)$$

Next, we apply the Chain Rule:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(H(g(x)) - H(f(x))\right) = H'(g(x))g'(x)-H'(f(x))f'(x) = h(g(x))g'(x)-h(f(x))f'(x)$$

For your integral, you have $h(t) = \sqrt{1+t^4}$, $g(x) = \cos x$, and $f(x)=0$. So, as others have pointed out, this becomes:

$$\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}\left(-\sin x\right) - 0 = -\sin x \sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}$$

Edit: Actually, Tsemo Aristide's and Parcly Taxel's answers do give a reason, and this answer is an alternate interpretation from Tsemo's and an expansion on Parcly's answer leading to the same result.

Comment: My answer explains why, exactly.

Comment: I updated my response.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thank you very much. Would it be okay to ask you to check if I did a similar problem correctly? I tried $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^2}\frac{\sin (tx)}{t}dt$$ and got $$\frac{2 \sin x^2}{x}.$$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to do this in another thread. Honestly, I am a bit surprised by this problem, as it requires a multivariate analogue of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Here, you have $$h(x,t) = \dfrac{\sin(tx)}{t}$$ which is a function of two variables. I do not believe this problem is going to have as nice a solution. In fact, I don't think it is even solvable without a firm understanding of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Wolframalpha gives the answer: $$\dfrac{3\sin(x^3)-\sin(x)}{x}$$ Again, this is not at all clear why this is the answer without a firm understanding of multivariable calculus, and even with it, I would still have had to work to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. Differentiating with respect to $\cos x$ gives $\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}$. Differentiating with respect to $x$ instead gives $-\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\cos x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt=F\circ G$ where $F(x)=\int_0^{ x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt $ and $G(x)=cos(x)$ apply $(F\circ G)'(x)=F'(G(x)).G'(x)$

$-sin(x)\sqrt{1+cos^4(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let an antiderivative of the integrand $f(t)$ be $F(t)$. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$\frac{d }{dx}\int_0^{\cos x}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt=\frac d{dx}(F(\cos x)-F(0))=f(\cos x)(-\sin x)=(-\sin x)\sqrt{1+\cos^4t}$$

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to multiply by the derivative of $\cos(x)$ and the $1$ at the end will not come. The correct answer is:

$$\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)} \times -\sin(x)$$